# What will a variable in a function get, when select statement returns no record?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

For example, in such a function:

```
create function
    example() returns int
as $$
declare
    x := 0;
begin
    x = ( select * from table_a where something>10 );
    return x;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

What will x be, when the query returns no record?

Comment: obviously the function failed as x = (select all), i reckon should only return 1 value or could be an aggregation of something

Comment: what if select only one column and it has no record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're declaring the function to return an int. Then the function *has* to return an int. You initialize x to 0, but then set it to null when you assign the result of a query that returns no rows.

So the value of x will be `null` typed to `int`, or `null::int`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION wtf() 
RETURNS int
AS $$
  DECLARE
    x int := 0;
  BEGIN
      RETURN x;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM wtf(); -- returns 0.

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION wtf() 
RETURNS int
AS $$
  DECLARE
    x int := 0;
  BEGIN
      x = ( SELECT 1 WHERE false );
      RETURN x;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM wtf(); -- returns null
 wtf 
-----

(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks! Very useful!